# Excel. Merge columns and remove duplicates

Tags: excel, merge

Having Column A - H with data that might or might not be duplicated in each column, I would like to get data from the columns merged into one column with removed duplicates.

Is this possible with FORMULA or do one need macro/vba?

I would prefer formula since the later is not my force (neither the first ;-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Sheets achieves this with the following formula:

```
 =sort(unique({A:A;B:B}))
```

[image]

Perhaps there is an Excel equivalent?

Comment: Copied columns to G.Sheets. entered the formula.. and happy camper = me..

Comment: There is a suggestion here for Excel, but a lot more complicated http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/16/unique-values-from-multiple-columns-using-array-formulas/

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro in vba, select the columns and then press (Alt + F11) and in the module of the sheet paste this code:

```
Sub MakeOneColumn()

Dim vaCells As Variant
Dim vOutput() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lRow As Long

If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
        If Selection.Count <= Selection.Parent.Rows.Count Then
            vaCells = Selection.Value

            ReDim vOutput(1 To UBound(vaCells, 1) * UBound(vaCells, 2), 1 To 1)

            For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
                For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
                    If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        vOutput(lRow, 1) = vaCells(i, j)
                    End If
                Next i
            Next j

            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection.Cells(1).Resize(lRow).Value = vOutput
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Then press F5 to execute the macro.